# Пытаюсь определить следующую функцию: y = x / sqrt(1. - (x / 2. / a) ^ 2); на С++

Tags: c++

Компилятор выдает ошибку - подчеркивает 1 и пишет:Выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу...
Переписывал через pow() -  тот же эффект.Эта функция в Python работает
нормально. Такая же проблема с другими функциями где есть sqrt(1.+ x/a).
Прошу подсказать в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: Приведите полностью тот кусок кода, в котором возникает ошибка и ее точный текст. На первый взгляд похоже, что ошибка вообще не в sqrt, а в том, что вы используете операцию `xor` с вещественными числами, а это не поддерживается стандартом. Если вы хотите возвести выражение в квадрат, то используйте функцию `pow` или просто умножьте его на себя. Такой код у меня работает: `double y = x / sqrt(1. - pow(x / 2. / a, 2));`

Comment: Спасибо, pow()  не помог, но помогло умножение его на себя

Answer (score 2):

оператор ^ не возводит в степень в c++, если хотите возвести в квадрат, можете просто написать `a*a`

на самом деле [оператор ^ это побитовое исключающее или](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B2_C_%D0%B8_C%2B%2B#%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)